# HaxeFlixel animations not playing

Tags: animation, haxe, haxeflixel

I'm trying to make a simple little game in HaxeFlixel, where you play as a ghost and you go around an apartment complex knocking on doors. There's a bit more to it than that, but that's the fundamental idea. Anyway, I've currently got the ghost moving from door to door, and knocking on them, but for some reason the animation where the tenant opens the door isn't triggering.

Here is the state:

```
package;

import flixel.addons.display.FlxBackdrop;
import flixel.FlxSprite;
import flixel.FlxState;
import flixel.FlxG;
import flixel.group.FlxTypedGroup;
import flixel.group.FlxTypedGroupIterator;
import flixel.text.FlxText;
import flixel.util.FlxPoint;
/**
 * ...
 * @author ...
 */

class GhostState extends FlxState
{
    var ghost:FlxSprite;
    var hall:FlxBackdrop;
    var wall:FlxSprite;
    var knock :Array<FlxText>;
    public var doors:FlxTypedGroup<Door>;
    public var speed = 0;
    public var inTransit:Bool;
    public var knockCount = 0;
    public var doneWithThisDoor = false;
    public var doorIndex = 0;

public function justPressed():Bool
{
    #if mobile
        var returnVal = false;
        for (touch in FlxG.touches.list)
        {
            returnVal = touch.justPressed;
        }
        return returnVal;
    #else
        return FlxG.mouse.justPressed;
    #end
}

public function pressed():Bool
{
    #if mobile
        var returnVal = false;
        for (touch in FlxG.touches.list)
        {
            returnVal = touch.pressed;
        }
        return returnVal;
    #else
        return FlxG.mouse.pressed;
    #end
}

public function justReleased():Bool
{
    #if mobile
        var returnVal = false;
        for (touch in FlxG.touches.list)
        {
            returnVal = touch.justReleased;
        }
        return returnVal;
    #else
        return FlxG.mouse.justReleased;
    #end
}

public function clickCoords():FlxPoint
{
    #if mobile
        var returnVal = new FlxPoint();
        var i=0;
        for (touch in FlxG.touches.list)
        {
            i++;
            returnVal.x += touch.screenX;
            returnVal.y += touch.screenY;
        }
        returnVal.x /= i;
        returnVal.y /= i;
        return returnVal;
    #else
        return new FlxPoint(FlxG.mouse.screenX, FlxG.mouse.screenY);
    #end
}

override public function create() 
{
    hall = new FlxBackdrop("assets/images/Stage3/hall wall.png", 0, 0, true, false);
    add(hall);

    doors = new FlxTypedGroup<Door> ();
    add(doors);

    #if web
        doors.add(new Door(((FlxG.width/2) - 259) + 465 + 175, (FlxG.height - 280) / 2, this, "assets/images/Stage3/door.png"));
    #else
        doors.add(new Door(((FlxG.width - 250-(175/2)-10) / 2) + 465 + 175, (FlxG.height - 280) / 2, this, "assets/images/Stage3/door.png"));
    #end

    ghost = new FlxSprite(FlxG.width / 2, FlxG.height / 2, "assets/images/Stage3/chicken ghost.png");
    ghost.loadGraphic("assets/images/Stage3/chicken ghost.png", true, 75, 100);
    ghost.animation.add("right", [0], 30, true);
    ghost.animation.add("forward", [1], 30, true);
    ghost.animation.add("back", [2], 30, true);
    add(ghost);

    speed = 0;
    super.create();

    knock = new Array();
    knock.push(new FlxText(ghost.x+25, ghost.y-35, -1, "*knock*", 20));
    knock.push(new FlxText(ghost.x+25, ghost.y - 85, -1, "*knock*", 20));
    for (member in knock)
    {
        member.color = 0x000000;
        add(member);
        member.kill();
    }

    nextDoor();
}

public function nextDoor()
{
    inTransit = true;
    if (ghost.x <= doors.members[doorIndex].x)
    {
        speed = 10;
        ghost.animation.play("right");
    }
    else
    {
        speed = 0;
        inTransit = false;
        doorIndex++;
        ghost.animation.play("forward");
    }
}

override public function update()
{
    hall.x -= speed;

    /*  var i = 0;
    while (i < doors.members.length)
    {
        var basic = doors.members[i++];

        if (basic != null && basic.exists && basic.active)
        {
            basic.update();
        }
    }*/

    if (inTransit)
    {
        nextDoor();
    }

    super.update();

    if (justPressed()&&!inTransit)
    {

        if (knockCount == 2)
        {
            knockCount = 0;
            for (member in knock)
            {
                member.kill();
            }
            doors.members[doorIndex-1].open();
            FlxG.watch.add(this,"doorIndex");
            nextDoor();
        }
        else 
        {
            knock[knockCount].revive();
            knockCount++;
        }
    }
}

}
```

And here is the `Door` class:

```
package;

import flixel.FlxSprite;
import flixel.FlxState;
import flixel.FlxG;

/**
 * ...
 * @author ...
 */
class Door extends FlxSprite
{
    var state:GhostState;
    var firstPass = true;

    public function new(X:Float=0, Y:Float=0, level:GhostState, ?SimpleGraphic:Dynamic) 
    {
        super(X, Y, SimpleGraphic);
        loadGraphic("assets/images/Stage3/door.png", true, 175, 250, false);
        animation.add("open", [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 30, false);
        animation.add("close", [5,4,3,2,1,0], 30, false);
        state = level;
        //this.animation.play("open");
        //state.doors.add(this);
    }

    public override function update():Void
    {
        if (firstPass)
        {
            if (isOnScreen())
            {
                state.doors.add(new Door(x + 465 + 175, (FlxG.height - 280) / 2, state));
                //state.add(new Door(x+465+175, (FlxG.height - 280) / 2, state));
                firstPass = false;
            }
        }

        this.x -= state.speed;
        if (this.x <= 0-this.width)
        {
            this.destroy();
        }
    }   

    public function open()
    {
        trace("open");
        animation.play("open", true, 0);
    }

    public function close()
    {
        animation.play("close", true, 0);
    }
}
```

Some information abut the code, as I'm bad at remembering to comment:

1. `doors` is a group that contains all doors in the state
2. `doorIndex` is the next door the ghost is supposed to move to next (so
   `doorIndex - 1` is the door it's at right now)

Why isn't it triggering? And how should I go about fixing this?

Comment: Not sure what animation are you trying to trigger.. is it Door's `open` animation? Can you check if your `animation.play` call is actually getting called?

Comment: it is, the game is even tracing "play" (the line right before animation.play()), but not actually playing the animation. I've managed to get it to play the first frame, but that's it

Comment: what version are you using? I think you are supposed to use `FlxSprite.animations` instead of `FlxSprite.animation`. Can you try that ?

Answer (score 0):

The `update(elapsed:Float)` function has an `elapsed` paremeter and inside of the function you override you must call the `super.update(elapsed)` parent function becase the animations are computed in this parent function.